# How to use $timeout effectively in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
 $scope.function_A();
 $scope.function_B();
```

and this DOES work:

```
 $scope.function_A();
 $timeout(function(){
     $scope.function_B();
 }),100;
```

This is due to the fact that `function_B` refers to a directive that hasn't been created yet by Angular. I believe that's why using `$timeout` fixes the problem.

My issue is: how to be sure that the `100 millisecond` timeout is correct and will always work? Is it better to somehow detect that `function_A` finished instead of using `$timeout`?

Comment: You might need to work with Promises if your functions have a delay. Try using **$q** promises. This way you can call another function after the first one resolves asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Promises.

If you require function A to finish it's work, before calling function B, it is a good idea to make it return a promise. Some angular services have methods that already return a Promise, e.g. `$http.get`. By using `$q` you can prepare your own promises. For example:

```
$scope.function_A = function() {
  //function code
  return $q.when();
}

$scope.function_A().then(function() {
  $scope.function_B();
});
```

Read more about `$q` and Promises [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback mechanism

```
$scope.function_A(callback){
  // your implementation
  callback() // add it at the end
}
```

Now call `function_B` inside `function_A`

```
$scope.function_A(function(){
  $scope.function_B();
});
```